# Troubleshooting the "Record rolled back because not all records were valid" in Process

Tags: process-builder, validation

One of my process fails when I am importing many records as a part of an ETL job with the following exception:

```
Record rolled back because not all records were valid
```

However the email I receive just mention a generic "Record rolled back because not all records were valid and the request was using AllOrNone header". Which specific fields are not passing is not visible from the logs

How does one investigate such an issue?

Comment: Salesforce will usually provide a bit more error information that the one line you have provided above. Can you share anymore with the Community?

Comment: I think it doesn't when the process operates on batches

Comment: What kind of ETL job/tool are you running? Is there a load order? Is it running in parallel? If running parallel, change to synchronous to see if problem resolves. Records could fail because of locking. I would also recommend is to break this down into a small chunk of records (one batch of 200 records) to see if it goes through to test process for bulkification, then increase # records until it breaks.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the problem. If my billing state is code is invalid, I get that error. However I need to find which batch is the offending one